# Issue in creating bar graph on plotly dash

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, plotly-dash

CODE:

```
    app.layout=html.Div([
    html.Div('WORLD HAPPINESS REPORT',
            style={
                'textAlign':'center',
                'color':'#F197C0',
                'fontWeight':'bold',
                'fontSize':'50px',
                'fontFamily':'Sans-serif',
                'border':({"width":"2px", "color":"black"})
            }),
    html.P('''The World Happiness Report is an annual report on the state of global happiness
and is currently participated by 155 countries. ''',
           style={
                'textAlign':'justify-text',
                'color':'#B49FDC',
                'fontWeight':'bold',
                'fontSize':'15px',
                'fontFamily':'Sans-serif'
            }),
    #for dropdown
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='select_year',
                options=[
                    {'label':'2015','value':2015},
                    {'label':'2016','value':2016},
                    {'label':'2017','value':2017},
                    {'label':'2018','value':2018},
                    {'label':'2019','value':2019},
                    {'label':'2020','value':2020},
                ],
                 multi=False,
                 value='2015',
                 style={'width': "40%"}
                 
                ), 
    
    dcc.Graph(id='the_graph',figure={})

])

@app.callback(
     Output(component_id='the_graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='select_year', component_property='value')] #this is for the argument of the func.written below.
)
def update_graph(option_selected):
    #print(option_slctd)
    #print(type(option_slctd))

    #container = "The year chosen by user was: {}".format(option_slctd)
    #if option_selected==2015:
        
    d1=data[data['Year']==option_selected]
    fig=go.Bar(
        x=df1['Country'],
        y=df1['Happiness Score']

        )
        
    return fig
```

I have to make a bar graph using plotly dash. But i am not getting the required output.I am not able to understand as to why the outcome is coming like that.
The output that im getting is :

[image: output image]

Can anyone please let me know what the issue is with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you didn't get a graph is because you were missing `go.Figure()`. Since I don't have the same data you are using, I used the data used on the official website and modified the dropdown values to match the data. The environment I verified is JupyterLab, so there is some code about it, but please ignore it.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
#from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = px.data.gapminder()

#app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([html.Div('WORLD HAPPINESS REPORT',
                                style={'textAlign':'center',
                                       'color':'#F197C0',
                                       'fontWeight':'bold',
                                       'fontSize':'50px',
                                       'fontFamily':'Sans-serif',
                                       'border':({"width":"2px", "color":"black"})
                                      }),
                       html.P('''The World Happiness Report is an annual report on the state of global happiness 
                       and is currently participated by 155 countries. ''',
                              style={'textAlign':'justify-text',
                                     'color':'#B49FDC','fontWeight':'bold',
                                     'fontSize':'15px',
                                     'fontFamily':'Sans-serif'}),#for dropdown
                       html.Br(),
                       dcc.Dropdown(id='select_year',
                                    options=[
                                        {'label':'1982','value':1982},
                                        {'label':'1987','value':1987},
                                        {'label':'1992','value':1992},
                                        {'label':'1997','value':1997},
                                        {'label':'2002','value':2002},
                                        {'label':'2007','value':2007},],
                                    multi=False,
                                    value='2015',
                                    style={'width': "40%"}),
                       dcc.Graph(id='the_graph',figure={})
])

@app.callback(
     Output(component_id='the_graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='select_year', component_property='value')] #this is for the argument of the func.written below.
)
def update_graph(option_selected):
    df1=data[data['year'] == option_selected]
    fig=go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=df1['country'], y=df1['lifeExp'])])
    return fig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
    #app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

[image]

Comment: Still no graph is made. I even copied the code on spider and run there but still the graph was not made .

Comment: I don't use spiders, so I don't know the cause. Can you check it in another development environment? For example, VSCode?

Comment: I also did it on anaconda, still its not working.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have copied all my code and checked it, right? Does the sample code in the official reference display well in the Anaconda environment? If not, please try [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dash).

Comment: As a final help, (1) run anaconda navigater and uninstall dash. (2) Execute only the following command with anaconda prompt. `conda install -c conda-forge dash`.

Comment: still nothing.The result is still the same. No graph

Comment: can you use my data and then you yourself see ?

Comment: how can I send you the data?

Comment: It seems like an environmental problem, not a data problem. Even if I run all my code, it's not visible in your environment, so replacing the data seems unlikely. If you can give me the location of the data in the form of a link, I will try to update the answer with your data.